# Button not getting displayed

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

```
<Page x:Class="WeichenSteuerung_neu.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:local="using:WeichenSteuerung_neu"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:converter="using:WeichenSteuerung_neu"
      mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="WeichenAbzweig&#xD;&#xA;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,156,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="WeicheAbzweig_Click" Width="133" Visibility="Visible" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="WeichenGerade&#xD;&#xA;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,213,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133" Click="WeicheGerade_Click" Visibility="Visible" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I'm writing a test program for "Remote Arduino" with UWP.
I have added two buttons to switch the pointer of a railway, but my `Button`s do not show in the window if I started the program.
There is just a blank white window!

So what do I have to add?
I tried set the `Visibilty` to `Visible` but this didn't work neither.

Design Time

[image: Design Time]

Runtime

[image: runtime]

Comment: Could you pleae add the complete XAML code? Is the `Grid` the root element inside the window?

Comment: @Herdo Thank u for your answer,  I have added the code below.

Comment: Could you add the content of that method to your question (not as a separate answer)? As addition: You might want to use the visual live explorer and inspect the visual tree of your running application.

Comment: private void WeicheAbzweig_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!direction)
            {
                _arduino.digitalWrite(1, PinState.HIGH);
                System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(20).Wait();
                _arduino.digitalWrite(1, PinState.LOW);
                direction = true;
            }
        }

Comment: or which method do you mean?

Comment: Can you provide the XAML of the `Window` that contains this `Page`? Pages are contained inside windows [Set Window.Content to a page by XAML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371056/set-window-content-to-a-page-by-xaml)

Comment: @sly They are not contained inside a `Window` directly - normally, they are inside a `Frame`. @J.Li Not this method. `OnLaunched` in your `App.xaml.cs`!

Comment: @Herdo 
           if (e.PrelaunchActivated == false)
            {
                if (rootFrame.Content == null)
                {
                    // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
                    // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
                    // parameter
                    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(WeichenSteuerung_neu.MainPage), e.Arguments);
                }
                // Ensure the current window is active
                Window.Current.Activate();
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

IMHO Margins are not the best friends of controls during runtime. I see you have set margins change your Grid like below.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="WeichenAbzweig&#xD;&#xA;" Width="133" Click="WeicheAbzweig_Click" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10"/>
        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="WeichenGerade&#xD;&#xA;" Width="133" Click="WeicheGerade_Click" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```