# how can I run a page in WPF c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to do something like this, but without XAML only C#

```
<Page x:Class="Mynamespace.MyPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Mynamespace"
        Title="MyPage"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
       <DockPanel>
            <...>

            </...>
        </DockPanel>
</Page>
```

This is what I've got so far:

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
   public MyPage()
     {
        Width = 525;
        Height = 350;

        // init elements
        DockPanel myDockPanel = new DockPanel();
        this.Content = myDockPanel;
        //...
    }

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        Application app = new Application();
        app.Run(new MyPage());
    }
}
```

I want my application to run the page. But Application.Run only works for windows. How can I get my application to run a Page?

Thanks for your Time!

Comment: What do you mean by _run a page_?

Comment: Add your page to a window (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371056/set-window-content-to-a-page-by-xaml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Application app = new Application();
    app.Run(new Window() { Content = new Frame() { Content = new MyPage() } });
}
```

Doing this you're loading a `Window`, with a `Frame` inside it. Inside this `Frame` there'll be your page.

According to [Microsoft's Page documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page(v=vs.110).aspx):

> (A `Page`) can be navigated to and hosted by **Windows Internet Explorer, NavigationWindow, and Frame**

(emphasis mine)